# Laravel 5 - relationships and handling data

Tags: model-view-controller, database-design, laravel-5

I have a system whereby you can create Documents of different types.  Initially, I had a new Model for each Document, but I don't think this is the best way because it can get messy fast.  So what I wanted to do is make a generic Documents model, and have individual documents come from this.  I have come up with the following type of design
[image: Database design]

So a Document can have one DocumentA and one DocumentB. DocumentA and DocumentB can only ever be created once per project which is why I have this relationship.  Now each form for each document has an upload button, where supporting documents can be uploaded alongside the generated document.  So Documents can have one to many FileUploads.

This is where I am confused.  A person visits my portal and selects the option to create DocumentA.  A form is now displayed to them which looks something like the following
[image: DocumentA]

So they enter the data for DocumentA, upload supporting documents, and then click submit.

Now I am thinking about how this can be handled within Laravel.

From what I understand, it will be something like the following

```
public function store(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    $document = new Documents();
    $document->documentName = 'Something';
    $document->documentA = new DocumentA();
    $document->documentA->startDate = Input::get('startDate');
    $document->documentA->endDate = Input::get('endDate');
    $document->documentA->notes = Input::get('notes');

    if (Input::hasFile('filePath')) {
        $files = Input::file('filePath');
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $fileString = "";
            $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $file->getClientOriginalName());

            $fileString .= public_path('uploads') . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $document->fileUpload = new FileUploads();
            $document->fileUpload->filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $document->fileUpload->mime = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $document->fileUpload->filepath = $fileString;
            $document->fileUpload->documentId = $document->id;
        }
    }

    $document->save();

    return Redirect::route('projects.documentA.edit', compact('project', 'documents'));
}
```

Really, looking for advice as to whether I am designing this correctly, and whether I am handling it correctly within Laravel.  I am going to end up with many different Documents, each of them accepting different input.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you want to create different tables for each doc? like you showed above for A and B. It will become messy. Why do not you just manage this in one table by using some identifier col?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I need one now :D

Answer (score 1):

you want to create different tables for each doc? like you showed above for A and B. It will become messy. Why do not you just manage this in one table by using some identifier col?

If you create one table for documents, one for fileUploads then you would create relationship between them like so

File upload model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class File extends Model
{
    /**
     * each file belongs to a document
     */
    public function document()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Document', 'foreign_key', 'primary_key');
    }
}
```

Document model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Document extends Model
{
    /**
     * document has multiple files
     */
    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\File', 'foreign_key', 'primary_key');
    }
}
```

Then you can access the records like this

```
$documents->files()->where('id', 1)->get();
//gives file associated with document id 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Ideally, I only want one Document model.  The only thing I can't figure out is that each Document has different inputs, so how can I handle this?  Thanks